# Power Query Excel how to parse information from a website popup page?

Tags: excel, parsing, web, powerquery

There is a stock exchange website. On the site in the corner there is a button "TRADING INFORMATION", when clicking on it, a page with information on trading on the exchange is called up. How can Power Query parse this page correctly? Link [here](https://kase.kz/ru/#trade_info_day). With the usual Get From Web, only the main page is parsed using this link, but the pop-up page is not. Please help.

Addition: In the pop-up window, you need to go to the Daily Trading Results tab and parse stock tables, etc.[image]

Comment: This may not help, but when I have done this in the past, I have created one Power Query to scan the source page and look for the link for the second page, and return that to Excel. Then name the cell containing the parse link, and use that name as the source for a second query. Don't know if that approach will work here. You can make the second query dependant on the first.

Comment: @DS_London not working